# Labeling two tables that display my content and other content

Tags: search, tables

I am introducing a new feature that allows instructors to copy from a previous course that either they themselves taught or some other instructor taught.

To search, the instructor will enter keyword or run a blank search.

The search results need to be split in two sections and labelled as the instructors own courses and courses taught by other instructors.

Is there a better label than "My Courses" and "Other Instructors' Courses"?  I feel the second label is long.

Comment: Would the instructor know that the other search results are from the other instructors?

Comment: Yes because there is a column labelled "Instructor" that will show the instructor name.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use the phrase "**Other Courses**" as it would inform the user that they are not courses he is teaching.

That said, I would recommend providing an option of a Global search along with a scoped search would allow him to either search across all the courses or just within his courses so that the user can restrict his options.To quote this article

> If you’re going to offer your users a scoped search, you should set
>   the default scope to all sections of the site. This makes it easy for
>   users to use the global search, which most will prefer. However, those
>   who want to use a scoped search can still do that. Scoped searches are
>   much like an advanced search. They’re best suited for users who know
>   exactly what they want and where to get it. The advantage of the
>   scoped search is that you don’t see the results for other sections of
>   the site. This is useful for the expert user, who understands how the
>   different site sections work. For everyone else, a global search with
>   scoped search results work best.
>   [image]

Then even if  users use the global search you can provide them with answers based upon scope as shown below

[image]

Comment: The only scoped search we have allows user to select the term (winter, spring, fall) and year the course was taught in.

Answer (score 0):

I would name them "My Courses" and "More Courses". The use of the word "My" implies that you're seeing all of your own, so "More" tells you that you're seeing other courses than the ones that are your own.

Another way to do it would be labeling them "My Courses" and "Colleague's Courses", or even titling the search results as "Courses taught by..." and labeling the sections as "Myself" and "Others".